# how to solve the keyerror when I load a CSV file using pandas

Tags: python-3.x

I use pandas to load a csv file and want to print out data of row, here is original data

[orginal data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMLoC.png)

I want to print out 'violence' data for make a bar chart, but it occuar a keyerror, here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

c_data=pd.read_csv('crime.csv')
print(c_data.head())

print (c_data['violence'])
```

and the error

[error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyehp.png)

[error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTLh5.png)

I tried use capital VIOLENCE,`print (c_data['VIOLENCE'])`,but also failed

[error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jafrK.png)

[error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exRYG.png)

can someone tell me how to work it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following if your data is small:

```
with open('crime.csv', 'r') as my_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_file)
    rows = list(reader)
    print rows[3]
```

If your data is big, try this:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('crime.csv', 'r') as my_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_file)
    print next(islice(reader, 3, 4))
```

Comment: Ok. I get it. You want to print out a row named 'VOILENCE'. However, the print function only prints the column with its name, and not a row. Let me check and I will give you a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197189/printing-a-specific-line-in-csv-file-with-python 

Hope the above link helps

Comment: with open(crime.csv, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    rows = list(reader)
    print (rows[3])    that is my new code, but it say name 'crime' is not defined

Comment: Type crime.csv between apostrophes. 

with open('crime.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
....

Comment: it works, thank you so much Sir. Btw, I have one more question, do u know how to make a bar chart or line chart base on my data

Comment: Well you could use matplotlib.plt to visualize your data. Just Google it. And I'm sure you will find a solution. As far as I know, visualizing a dataset is very easy, I just don't know the exact syntax of the code. Happy coding!